# Find sequence of matches in string without spaces (using php)

Tags: php, sequences

I'm hoping for some help.
I thought this would be fairly trivial - if a little inefficent, but I'm clearly missing something.

I've been given the task of identifying possible sequence matches with a string of numbers.
The idea is to take a string of numbers, and see if any sequences of numbers from a library file exist.
String = 123456789
Library = 12, 34, 56, 78, 9, 123, 456, 789, 1234, 56789

I should generate a multidimensional array of matches,
(0) (0 - 12) (1 - 34) (2 - 56) (3 - 78) (4 - 9)
(1) (0 - 123) (1 - 456) (2 - 789)
(2) (0 - 1234) (1 - 56789)

Here's my code

```
$library = array('12', '34', '56', '78', '9', '123', '456', '789', '1234', '56789' );
$string = "123456789";
$string = trim(strtolower($string));

echo $string."<hr/>";

function possibles ($library, $string, $c, $array){
  $string2 = $string;
  $c = 0;

  foreach ($library as $sequence){

    if(strpos($string2, $sequence) === 0){
      $array[$c] = $sequence;
      $string2 = substr($string2, strlen($sequence));
      echo "-".$sequence."-".$string2."-".$c;
      possibles($library, $string2,  $c, $array);
    } else {$string2 = $string;
      echo "*<br/>";
      continue;
    }
    $c++;
    $string2=$string;
  }
  return $array;
}

$array = array();
print_r(possibles($library,$string, $c, $array));
```

(Yes, I tried to format it)

The above is set to output with echos of the content found.
1) That content isn't what I was expecting
2) That content doesn't match the printed output from the Print_r

Please help, as I cannot see what I've done wrong :(

[APPEND

Here's a reworked version

```
$library = array('12', '34', '56', '78', '9', '123', '456', '789', '1234', '56789' );
$string = "123456789";
$string = trim(strtolower($string));

function possibles ($library, $string, $c, $array, $t){
$string2 = $string;
$strlen = strlen($string2);
$c = 0;

foreach ($library as $sequence){
  $sequence = trim($sequence);
  $sequencelen = strlen($sequence);
  if(strpos($string2, $sequence) !== 0  ||  $strlen < $sequencelen){
    break;
  }else {
    echo $sequence." ";
    $array[$c][] = $sequence;
    $string2 = substr($string2, strlen($sequence));
    possibles ($library, $string2, $c, $array, $t);
  }

}$c++;
return $array;
}
$t = array();
$array = array();
print_r(possibles($library,$string, $c, $array, $t));
```

Which outputs;
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 34 [2] => 56 [3] => 78 [4] => 9 ) )
That's almost right.  The sequence is there, but only the first.
I expect to also see;
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 456 [2] => 789 ) )
Array ( [2] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => 56789 ) )

There, I hope that makes it a little clearer?

[APPEND]
Thinking about it, there should be other sequences as well?
12 34 5678 // 1234 56 78 9 // 123 456 78 9 etc.?

Comment: What is the logic that defines your expected output?

Comment: Your recursion doesn't make sense: you never use the returned array from your recursive calls, nor do you pass the array by reference, so the recursion ends up having no effect on the array returned to your print_r call.

Do you have to end up with a multidimensional array? Must you use recursion? I can think of simple non-recursive solutions that would give you a single array.

Comment: The logic is that I expect to get results that show sequences of matches.  The first encountering match of library in string is "12".  This is then removed from the string.  The next match is "34", and should be added to the array, along with "12". this repeats until the string is consumed or no more matches occur.  Then the process is meant to go again ... as "12...34...56.." has been found, the next match set is "123" ... wash rinse and repeat.  I think I see what you mean about not using the recursed results... hmmmm.

Comment: If you don't remove the match from the string, you can still continue searching. if (strpos($match) !== FALSE) tells you if you have a match anywhere in the string, not just at the first position. This way you can just iterate through your numbers array and search each on the string. Done.

Comment: That will simply provide an array of matches, regardless of sequence.  The point of the above is to collect matches in a sequence based on occurence within the original string.  -  Further, I've double checked, and there is collection within the recursion when I echo during the function, as it outputs the sequence.  What doesn't happen is outputting it - so I've stuffed up adding to the $array?

Comment: Is there any guarantee of order for $library and $string?

Comment: Not really, no.  Library could be organised before hand, either numerically(Asc/Desc), by length(Asc/Desc) or both (Asc+Asc/Asc+Desc/Desc+Asc/Desc+Desc).  String is whatever I get passed (large files with 2K lines, each line being a numerical string between 12 and 128 characters long).  I suppose I could also sort that similar to the library...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to return an array containing all matching elements:

```
function getMatches($search, $string) {
    $matches = array();
    // if it's an array, go through each element and add any matches
    if (is_array($search)) {
        // let's not consider nested arrays for now
        foreach($search AS $s) {
            if (strpos($string, $s) !== FALSE) {
                 $matches[] = $s;
            }
        }
    }
    // otherwise we just search right away
    elseif (strpos($string, $search) !== FALSE) {
        $matches[] = $search;
    }
    // all matching entries are now in this one-dimensional array
    return $matches;
}
```

Based on your $library search, this would return an array ([0] => 12 [1] => 34 [2] => 56 , [3] => 78, [4] => 9, [5] => 123, [6] => 456, [7] => 789, [8] => 1234, [9] => 56789) )

Comment: That does indicate Sequences.  That simply runs through finding matches.

Comment: What do you mean be 'Sequences' ? The returned array will contain matches in the same order as they were listed in your search query, so in your example, you would get an array exactly the same as your $library array. Can you define the exact logic that would determine when a separate array would be made? E.g. [0]=>{12, 34, 56, 78, 9}, [1]=>{123, 456, 789} - why 2 arrays instead of one?

Comment: You mean, provide examples of expected output, like I did in the original post and in the appended parts?  The idea is to collect the possible permutations of matches from the library to the string.  Logic?  When you parse the string and run out of characters.  When you reach the end of possible permutations/computations of the previous.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, yes. I didn't realize that removing sections of the string was integral to your output. I'll try to modify my answer in a few hours to take that into account. EDIT: Just saw your append, and I'm not sure how to include those in the result set without actually running some code on my end, so it may be longer before I can answer.

Comment: Not a problem, and any help is appreciated.  I've been looking at it, wondering if I need a temp array to run with, and possibly a sub-function, as well as a way to set the key and update the key to represent the string (as this can help remove dupes without having to process and compare nested arrays ... instead, conjoin the values and make that the key?) ((This turned out far more complicated than I thought :( ))